Why do I get large random values when using scanf("%f", &intVar)? How do float inputs get converted to these values?
I know I used the wrong format specifier in my C program when reading floats into int variables using scanf("%f", &variable).
I don't know how the program yields large random values.
How do the input values get converted to these random values?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Width Height --> Floating Point

float findArea (float width, float height)
{
  float area;
  area = width* height;
  printf("width:%f\n",width);
  printf("height:%f\n",height);
  return area;
}


int main()
{
  int heightRectangle, widthRectangle;
  float area;
  printf("Enter width: ");
  scanf("%f",&widthRectangle);
  printf("Enter height: ");
  scanf("%f", &heightRectangle);
  area = findArea(widthRectangle,heightRectangle);
  printf("The area of your given rectangle is: %f \n",area);

  return 0;
}

Output:
Enter width: 5.0
Enter height: 2.5
width:1084227584.000000
height:1075838976.000000
The area of your given rectangle is: 1166454293721513984.000000 

Size of int and float in my system is 4 bytes. I used sizeof operator to determine that.
Compiler Information:
I am using online compiler programiz
Guys, once again I know I used wrong format specifier.I'm just expecting answer which explains how the values 5.0 and 2.5 are getting converted to 1084227584 and 1075838976.

The behaviour of the program is undefined because of that wrong format specifier (or rather the wrong type with which your variables are defined). This means you can observe any result whatsoever---nothing is guaranteed or specified. It could be interesting to find out what exactly happens so that you see what you see; however. bear in mind that with a different compiler, or with the same compiler in a slightly different environment, your observations might in principle be very different.

@JKR, printing floating point with "%a" and integers with "%x" can make it easier to see common (maybe shifted) bit patterns.

Have a play with an online IEEE-754 converter such as this one to see how floats get represented in binary.

The %f in scanf("%f",&widthRectangle); instructs scanf to convert input into the encoding scheme used for a float object and to store the bits that result from that encoding in the memory pointed to by widthRectangle.
Since, in main, widthRectangle is declared to be an int, when widthRectangle is used in findArea(widthRectangle,heightRectangle), the program interprets those bits using the encoding scheme used for an int. Then, because findArea is declared to have float parameters, the program converts that value to the float type and passes that to findArea.
So the value later printed by printf("width:%f\n",width) is the result of interpreting the encoding of 5 as a float using the decoding for int.
Everything we represent in a computer is encoded by some arbitrary assignment of what bits represent what value. int and float types use different rules for what bits represent what values.
For int types, two’s complement is usually used. First, we start with rules
for encoding a non-negative integer in binary:
To encode a non-negative integer x in w bits (w for “width”):

Let bi denote the bit that is i bits from the right, starting with b0 for the rightmost bit.
For i from 0 to w−1:

If x is even or odd, set bi to 0 or 1, respectively.
Set x to x/2, truncating any fraction.


If x is not zero after the above, it does not fit in w bits. Declare an error and stop.

To encode an integer x in w-bit two’s complement:

If x exceeds 2w−1−1 or is less than −2w−1, it does not fit. Declare an error and stop.
If x is negative, set x to x + 2w.
Encode x in w-bit binary, per above.

For float types, a multi-part encoding of the number with separate sign, exponent, and significand portions is used. Most commonly, the IEEE-754 binary32 format is used:

If x is negative or not, let S be the bit 1 or 0, respectively, and set x to |x|.
Set an exponent e to 0.
While 2 ≤ x:

Set e to e+1.
Set x to x/2 (retaining any fraction).


While x < 1 and −126 < e:

Set e to e−1.
Set x to 2x.


Set f to 223•x, rounded to an integer. (There is a choice of rounding methods, not discussed here.)
If 224 ≤ f, set e to e+1 and set f to f/2. (f will now be exactly 223, because this happens only when the rounding above makes f 224.)
If 127 < e, x was too large. Declare overflow, produce S concatenated with the bits 1111111100000000000000000000000, which represent +∞ or −∞ according to S, and stop.
If f < 223:

Let E be a string of eight 0 bits.
Let F be the result of encoding f in 23 bits in binary.


Otherwise:

Let E be the result of encoding e+127 in eight bits in binary.
Let F be the result of encoding f−223 in 23 bits in binary.


The resulting bit string is the concatenation of S, E, and F.

For x = 5, this operates:

In step 1, 5 is not negative, so S is set to 0.
In step 2, e is set to 0.
In step 3:

5 is greater than 2, so e is increased to 1 and x is changed to 2.5.
2.5 is greater than 2, so e is increaed to 2, and x is changed to 1.25.
1.25 is not greater than 2, so the loop in step 3 stops.


In step 4, 1.25 is not less than 1, so the loop in step 4 does not start.
In step 5, f is set to 223•1.25 = 10,485,760 = A0000016.
In step 6, f is not greater than or equal to 224, so nothing is done.
In step 7, e is not greater than 127, so nothing is done.
In step 8, f is not less than 223, so nothing is done.
In step 9, E is set to the eight bits resulting from encoding 127+2 in binary, which is the string 10000001, and F is set to the result of encoding 10,485,760 − 223 in 23 bits in binary, which is 01000000000000000000000.
In step 10, the result is the concatenation of 0, 10000001, and 01000000000000000000000, making
01000000101000000000000000000000.

When the bit string 01000000101000000000000000000000 is interpreted as an int, the result is 1,084,227,584.
We can also reverse this:
In hexadecimal, 1,084,227,584 is 40A00000. In 32-bit binary, this is 0 10000001 01000000000000000000000. I inserted spaces to show where we separate the number into parts due to the floating-point encoding scheme. The first bit, 0, means positive. The next eight bits, 10000001, are an encoding of the exponent (and one bit of the significand, a leading 1). As a binary numeral, they would be the number 129. The floating-exponent exponent is this number minus 127, so it is 2. The last 23 bits are the last 23 bits of the significand. Together with the leading 1 bit, they represent binary 1.01000000000000000000000, which is 1.25 in decimal. Thus, the floating-point number represented is + 22 • 1.25, which is 5.
Similarly, 1,075,838,976 is hexadecimal 40200000, binary 0 10000000 01000000000000000000000, which differs only in that the exponent field is binary 10000000, decimal 128, so it represents the exponent 1. The floating-point number represented is + 21 • 1.25, which is 2.5.

You might want to mention undefined behavior as an introduction to your explanation... The OP knows about the incorrect conversion specifier and wants an explanation, which you provide in detail, but it seems important to specify that this behavior is not guaranteed.

@chqrlie: No. The question explicitly asks why they are getting the observed values, and “undefined behavior” does not answer that question. It is not an explanation; undefined behavior is an absence of rules, not a presence of cause. The author states in the first sentence they know they used the wrong specifier. They state it again in the penultimate sentence. In the last sentence, they state they are just expecting an answer which explains the observed values. The author has explicitly ruled out other discussion, and I answered the question according to their guidelines.

Assumed background knowledge: binary/bit-representations of integers and floating point numbers.

It boils down to

bitstring(5.0) == 01000000101000000000000000000000 (base 2) == 1084227584 (base 10) and
bitstring(2.5) == 01000000001000000000000000000000 (base 2) == 1075838976 (base 10)

When you call scanf with a %f format specifier, it will parse the input into a single precision IEEE 754 representation. E.g. 5.0 will be parsed into 01000000101000000000000000000000. This is the exact value stored at &widthRectangle in your case.
But since widthRectangle is actually an int, this bit representation is (re)interpreted as an integer when passing to findArea. So, the value ends up being the corresponding decimal (as in base 10) integer for 01000000101000000000000000000000, which is 1084227584.
Note that (as others have also pointed out), using incorrect format specifiers results in undefined behavior in general, and consequently you might observe different outputs from different compilers. In this case the result ends up being "logical" probably because float and int have the same size and alignment. But again, you can never rely on this as it is UB.
